# School Database in java

Tags: java

I was wondering if anyone had the time/patience to help me with this problem I'm having.
Basically all I'm trying to do is create a **Very** simple student database system and it doesn't seem to be working for me. This is my Main Class, Student Class and Subjects Class.

Subjects Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;//ArrayList Import.
public class Subjects
{
    /*(Public Variables)*/
    public static String subjectName;
    public static String subjectTutor;
    public static ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    public static ArrayList<Student> mathsList  = new ArrayList<Student>();
    public static ArrayList<Student> excelList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    public static ArrayList<Student> javaList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    public static ArrayList<Student>classList= new ArrayList<Student>();

    public Subjects(String sName)//If statement that will select the correct
    tutor for the class
    {
        subjectName = sName;

        if (subjectName == "maths")
        {
            subjectTutor= "Jennifer";
        }
        if (subjectName == "excel")
        {
            subjectTutor= "Ed";
        }
        if (subjectName == "java")
        {
            subjectTutor = "Brendan";
        }
    }
    public static void printSubjectDetails()//Print Subject Details Method//Print the subject details listed below.
    {
        System.out.println("Subjects are " + subjectName + " and tutor is " + subjectTutor);
    }
    public static void printStudentList()
    {

    }

    //Method for adding students to different classes
    public static void addMathsStudent(Student localStudent)
    {
        mathsList.add(localStudent);
    }

    public static void addexcelStudent(Student localStudent)
    {
        excelList.add(localStudent);
    }
    public static void addStudent(Student localStudent)
    {
        studentList.add(localStudent);
    }
    public static void addjavaStudent(Student localStudent)
    {
        javaList.add(localStudent);
    }
    public static void printClass()//Print method that prints out the selected class when        called in the main method.
    {
        System.out.println(subjectName + " Class List");

        for(Student i : studentList)
        {
            Student.printStudent();
        }
    }
}
```

Student Class

```
import java.util.Scanner;//Scanner Import.
public class Student
{
    //variables
    public static String studentFName;
    public static String  studentLName;
    int studentGrade;

    public Student()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Operations for student class.
        System.out.println("Please enter First Name.");
        studentFName = input.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter student Surname.");
        studentLName = input.next();
    }


    //Print operations for student class.
    public static  void printStudent()
    {
        System.out.println("Students First Name is:" + studentFName);
        System.out.println("Students Surname is:" + studentLName);
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AppMenu {

    // An Auto-generated method stub. (created when making the class.)
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        appmenu();
    }
    public static <printClass> void appmenu()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
        System.out.println("Enter [.1] to enroll a student");
        System.out.println("Enter [.2] to View Class List");
        System.out.println("Enter [.3] to Remove Students");
        System.out.println("Enter [.4] to Clear Class Lists");
        System.out.println("Enter [.5] to Exit The App");
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");

        //Case and Break.
        String choice = input.next();
        {
            switch(choice)
            {
                case "1":
                    Student s1 = new Student();
                    System.out.println("What class would you like to enroll in?");
                    System.out.println("Press [.1] Enroll In Maths");
                    System.out.println("Press [.2] Enroll In Excel");
                    System.out.println("Press [.3] Enroll In Java");
                    System.out.println("Press [.4] Enroll In All of the above");
                    choice = input.next();
                    switch(choice)
                    {
                        case "1":
                            Subjects.addMathsStudent(s1);
                            appmenu();
                            break;
                        case "2":
                            Subjects.addexcelStudent(s1);
                            appmenu();
                            break;
                        case "3":
                            Subjects.addjavaStudent(s1);
                            appmenu();
                            break;
                        case "4":
                            Subjects.addStudent(s1);
                            appmenu();


                    }
                case "2":
                    System.out.println("Press [.1] to View Maths Class List");
                    System.out.println("Press [.2] to View Excel Class List");
                    System.out.println("Press [.3] to View Java Class List");
                    choice = input.next();
                    switch(choice)
                    {
                        case "1":
                            Subjects.printSubjectDetails();
                            appmenu();
                            break;
                        case "2":
                            Subjects.printSubjectDetails();
                            appmenu();
                            break;
                        case "3":
                            Subjects.printSubjectDetails();
                            appmenu();
                            break;
                        case "4":
                            Subjects.printSubjectDetails();
                            appmenu();
                            break;
                    }
                case "3":
                    System.out.println("Which student would you like to remove ");
                    Subjects.printStudentList();
                    Subjects.studentList();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What part of it isn't working?

Comment: _It's not working_ - succinct, accurate and totally useless. Explain __what__ isn't working.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Take a moment to read over how to ask a good question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Sorry Mike, the part that isn't working currently is the printing of the student list.

Comment: case "1":
            Subjects.printSubjectDetails();
            appmenu();
            break;

Answer (score 6):

Without running your code, your first problem is here...

```
public Subjects(String sName) {

    subjectName = sName;

    if (subjectName == "maths") {
        subjectTutor = "Jennifer";
    }
    if (subjectName == "excel") {
        subjectTutor = "Ed";
    }
    if (subjectName == "java") {
        subjectTutor = "Brendan";
    }
}
```

`String` comparison in Java is not done with `==` but is done with the `String#equals` method which means it should become...

```
public Subjects(String sName) {
    subjectName = sName;
    if ("maths".equals(subjectName)) {
        subjectTutor = "Jennifer";
    }
    if ("excel".equals(subjectName)) {
        subjectTutor = "Ed";
    }
    if ("java".equals(subjectName)) {
        subjectTutor = "Brendan";
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what this is suppose to be `Subjects.studentList();`, but I'd discourage you from trying to access the fields of an object/class directly and rely on appropriate management methods

Also,

```
switch (choice) {
    case "1":
        //...
    case "2":
        //...
    case "3":
```

Has no `break` in it, which means if `choice` is `1`, case 2 and 3 will also be executed...

Instead of relying on `static`, create a `Subject` class for each subject you want to manage and add students/tutors to each instance of the `Subject`, this will make the management much easier in the long run.

Case in point...

```
public class Student
{
    //variables
    public static String studentFName;
    public static String  studentLName;
```

This means that no matter how many instance of `Student` you create, they will all have the same first and last names...

Consider using some kind of loop to manage the menu menu rather the continuously calling `appmenu`, while it would take a very long time, you will eventually end up with a stack overflow exception...

**Update with runnable example**

This is the code I came up with when I was looking for other problems...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AppMenu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        appmenu();
    }

    public static <printClass> void appmenu() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Subject maths = new Subject("Maths", "Jennifer");
        Subject excel = new Subject("Excel", "Ed");
        Subject java = new Subject("Java", "Brendan");

        String choice = null;
        do {

            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
            System.out.println("Enter [.1] to enroll a student");
            System.out.println("Enter [.2] to View Class List");
            System.out.println("Enter [.3] to Remove Students");
            System.out.println("Enter [.4] to Clear Class Lists");
            System.out.println("Enter [.5] to Exit The App");
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");

            //Case and Break.
            choice = input.next();
            {
                switch (choice) {
                    case "1":
                        Student s1 = new Student();
                        System.out.println("What class would you like to enroll in?");
                        System.out.println("Press [.1] Enroll In Maths");
                        System.out.println("Press [.2] Enroll In Excel");
                        System.out.println("Press [.3] Enroll In Java");
                        System.out.println("Press [.4] Enroll In All of the above");
                        choice = input.next();
                        switch (choice) {
                            case "1":
                                maths.addStudent(s1);
                                break;
                            case "2":
                                excel.addStudent(s1);
                                break;
                            case "3":
                                java.addStudent(s1);
                                break;
                            case "4":
                                maths.addStudent(s1);
                                excel.addStudent(s1);
                                java.addStudent(s1);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        System.out.println("Press [.1] to View Maths Class List");
                        System.out.println("Press [.2] to View Excel Class List");
                        System.out.println("Press [.3] to View Java Class List");
                        choice = input.next();
                        switch (choice) {
                            case "1":
                                maths.printSubjectDetails();
                                maths.printClass();
                                break;
                            case "2":
                                excel.printSubjectDetails();
                                excel.printClass();
                                break;
                            case "3":
                                java.printSubjectDetails();
                                java.printClass();
                                break;
                            case "4":
                                maths.printSubjectDetails();
                                maths.printClass();
                                excel.printSubjectDetails();
                                excel.printClass();
                                java.printSubjectDetails();
                                java.printClass();
                                break;

                        }
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        System.out.println("Which student would you like to remove ");
                        break;
                }
            }
        } while (!"5".equals(choice));
    }

    public static class Subject {
        /*(Public Variables)*/

        public String subjectName;
        public String subjectTutor;
        public ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

        public Subject(String sName, String tutor) {
            subjectName = sName;
            subjectTutor = tutor;
        }

        public void printSubjectDetails()//Print Subject Details Method//Print the subject details listed below.
        {
            System.out.println("Subjects are " + subjectName + " and tutor is " + subjectTutor);
        }

        public void addStudent(Student student) {
            studentList.add(student);
            System.out.println("Now have " + studentList.size() + " students for " + subjectName);
        }

        public void printClass()//Print method that prints out the selected class when        called in the main method.
        {
            System.out.println(subjectName + " Class List");

            for (Student i : studentList) {
                i.printStudent();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Student {

        //variables
        private String studentFName;
        private String studentLName;
        int studentGrade;

        public Student() {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            //Operations for student class.
            System.out.println("Please enter First Name.");
            studentFName = input.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter student Surname.");
            studentLName = input.next();
        }

        //Print operations for student class.
        public void printStudent() {
            System.out.println("Students First Name is:" + studentFName);
            System.out.println("Students Surname is:" + studentLName);
        }
    }
}
```